# What are the differences between different Elastic data stream types?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

[Elastic docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/7.15/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-data_stream_type) mentions that Elastic data stream supports the following types: `logs`, `metrics` and `synthetics`. What are the differences between these types?

I tested storing some data as `logs` and `metrics` types separately and I don't see any difference when querying the data. Are both types interchangeable or are they stored differently?

Answer (score 3):

Those are different types of data sets collected by the new [Elastic Agent and Fleet integration](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/fleet/current/index.html):

- The `logs` type is for logs data, i.e. what Filebeat used to send to Elasticsearch.
- The `metrics` type is for metric data, i.e. what Metricbeat used to send to Elasticsearch
- The `synthetics` type is for uptime and status check data, i.e. what Heartbeat used to send to Elasticsearch.

Now, with Fleet, [all the Beats have been refactored](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elastic-agent-and-fleet-make-it-easier-to-integrate-your-systems-with-elastic) into a single agent called Elastic Agent which can do all of that, so instead of having to install all the *Beats, you just need to install that agent and enable/disable/configure whatever type of data you want to gather and index into Elasticsearch. All of that through a nice, powerful and centralized Kibana UI.

Beats are now simply Elastic Agent modules that you can enable/disable and they will all write their data into indexes that [follow a new taxonomy and naming scheme](https://www.elastic.co/blog/an-introduction-to-the-elastic-data-stream-naming-scheme), which is based on those types, which are nothing more than a generic way describing the nature of data they contain, i.e. logs, metrics, synthetics, etc.